# Setting Style property in code - dependency property FontSizeProperty name does not exist in current context in silverlight library

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, styles

This is similar to my previous question, but that solution did not solve this problem.

fontSizeProperty is not being recognized when I move a method from my Silverlight MainPage code behind (which worked) to a new class in a silverlight library

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class DataGridBuilder
    {
        private static Style BuildHeaderStyle(string tooltip)
        {
            Style newGridHeaderStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
            newGridHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = FontSizeProperty, Value = 9.0 });
            newGridHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = FontWeightProperty, Value = FontWeights.Bold });
            return newGridHeaderStyle;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: Per MSDN for FontSizeProperty, I do include System.Windows reference, and "using System.Windows.Control"

Based on answers below, I changed "Property = FontSizeProperty" to "Property=DataGridColumnHeader.FontSizeProperty" etc., like this:

```
    private static Style BuildHeaderStyle(string tooltip)
    {
        FontWeight fw = FontWeights.Bold;
        Style newGridHeaderStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
        newGridHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = DataGridColumnHeader.FontSizeProperty, Value = 9.0 });
        newGridHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = DataGridColumnHeader.FontWeightProperty, Value = FontWeights.Bold });
        newGridHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = DataGridColumnHeader.ContentTemplateProperty, Value = CreateDataGridHeaderTemplate(tooltip) });
        return newGridHeaderStyle;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `Control.FontSizeProperty` and `Control.FontWeightProperty` instead.

Your `MainPage` is a user control, which has `Control` as a superclass and hence inherits the above two dependency properties.  Your static class isn't a subclass of `Control` so it doesn't inherit these dependency properties.

Comment: Both this answer and @Julien Lebosquain are correct.  I marked this one as answer because it has more explanation.  Thanks Luke.

Answer (score 1):

`FontSizeProperty` is defined on `Control`, which you do not derive from, so you have to use `Control.FontSizeProperty`.